# rails function called from jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

looking for a way to implement a call to a rails method from within jquery, but without rendering anything, just in the background.

The idea is that I have a select tag with multiselect enabled, my model has a boolean field called active, and when an element is selected, active would be set to true, otherwise false.

in my application.js i have this:

```
$(".multiselect").change(function() {
    $("option", this).each(function() {
        if(this.selected) {
             // do true for checked
        } else {
             // do false for unchecked
        }
    }
});
```

this function works fine, but i'm stuck at two parts, i know i can get the id of the object from (this).val(), but where should I put the function that would find it and change the active field? In the controller or in the model? Mind I don't need to render anything, just do things in the background.

And secondly, how do i call this function from within my jquery?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the form every time the change event gets triggered. This would get mapped to a function in the controller, which will render nothing.

You could do something like this

in your application.js

```
$(".multiselect").change(function() {
  $("option", this).each(function() {
    if(this.selected) {
         // do true for checked
    } else {
         // do false for unchecked
    }
  }
  //submitting form after doing stuff
  $.post($(this).parent("form") .... );
});
```

In your controller you would probably map it to an 'update' method

```
def update
  # logic to update active attribute of model
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is not inside a form (at least not for now). So if I have an update method should i put something like: def update @foo = Foo.find(params[:id]) @foo.active = true/false end ? but how would i call this function from the js without using form? can i say $.post({#update}(this.val())? or something like this to pass on the id?

Comment: You could do it via a GET request, but is there a specific reason why you don't want to wrap the select list in a form? A good convention is to always do a POST request, when you are changing a resource.

Comment: Also, i forgot to add, to do this without submitting a form you would have to do a jQuery.get()
Something like this - 
$.get("/some_URL", {foo_active : $(this).val()}, null, "script");